# Global javascript object not defined error?

Tags: javascript, variables, global

I don't know if this is too localized or not but I don't have much code. The problem I am having is an object being declared in a global js file named `System.js` called `budgetModel` which holds data for the entire web app is showing as undefined.

I created a class like object called `BudgetModel` in js within the `System.js` file and when a user logs in the website directs them to a page called `index.php` which onload executes two methods called `setupSystem()` and then `setup()`.

Near the bottom of the html before the closing 'body' tag I placed two scripts, the `System.js` and a setup function to load the data that was passed from php to javascript using json as the variable `budgetcost` and another called `budgetexp`:

```
<script src="util/js/System.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function setup(){

    budgetModel.setCost(budgetcost, budgetexp);

}
</script>
```

Also in the `System.js` file I have this global function and variable:

```
var budgetModel;

function setupSystem(){

    budgetModel = new BudgetModel();

}
```

The `setupSystem` function is called before the `setup` function is called within the `index.php` file. The error I get is that it complains the `budgetModel` variable is not defined. How can this be fixed or is it even possible and if it is possible should my `System.js` script line be somewhere else?

EDIT: 
I fixed the problem. There was a very very small syntax error in the `System.js` file.
I also noticed that window. syntax doesn't matter either way if the variable is declared global or not. Sorry for the bother everyone x_x

EDIT2:

Here is as much code as I can provide:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Test Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="util/css/globalStyles.css">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>
<body onload="setup();">

...

<script src="util/js/System.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setup(){

        if (typeof(budgetcost) !== 'undefined'){

            setupSystem();

            budgetModel.setModel(budgetcost, budgetexp);

            teamAssumpModel.setModel(teamagents);

        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
```

System.js:

```
var budgetModel;
var teamAssumpModel;


function setupSystem(){

    window.budgetModel = new BudgetModel();

    window.teamAssumpModel = new TeamAssumpModel();

}

function TeamAssumpModel() {

    this.teamagents = [[]];

    this.setModel = function(teamagents){
        this.teamagents = teamagents;
    };

    this.getAgents = function(){
        return this.teamagents;
    };

}

function BudgetModel(){

    this.budgetcost = [[]];
    this.budgetexp = [[]];

    this.setModel = function(budgetcost, budgetexp){
        this.budgetcost = budgetcost;
        this.budgetexp = budgetexp;
    };

    this.getExp = function(){
        return this.budgetexp;
    };

    this.getCost = function(){
        return this.budgetcost;
    };

}
```

So this is pretty much what what I have. budgetModel works in the index.php but when I include this same file into another php file it reads as undefined. What else is required to make it visible to other php files?

Comment: *"The `setupSystem` function is called before the `setup` function is called within the index.php file."* How sure are you about that? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Where are you getting the error from? `setup` or `setupSystem`?

Comment: May not be relevant, but global variables should be explicitly defined for readability and for confirmation that it is in fact a global variable. I.E. var window.budgetModel = new BudgetModel( ); ( window. ) is the syntax to declaring a javascript variable globaly.

Comment: Put a break point in the method to make sure it's called as expected

Comment: the functions are called in the body tag in the `index.php` file `<body onload="setupSystem(); setup();">`

Comment: @Cian If `budgetModel` is defined in this `System.js` file, then you're loading that file _before_ the `<body>` loads, right?

Comment: No, sorry I edited the text "Near the bottom of the html before the closing 'body' tag"

Comment: Is your site accessible? Can you provide a link?

Comment: No it is not accessible from the web right now. It can't at the moment it is only setup for Apache on my computer.